# Translation Golf XLV - The Rains of Castamere (the Lannister song)

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

It's all over now: **Charlie** won with a [157-char answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30415).
And now his watch has ended.

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game! If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

Quoting [*A Wiki of Ice and Fire*](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_Rains_of_Castamere):

*House Reyne was obliterated after they rebelled against their liege lord, Tytos Lannister, who was perceived as weak by his own vassals. To restore Lannister dominance, Tytos's eldest son and heir, Ser Tywin Lannister, marched against the upstart Lord of Castamere, Roger Reyne, known as the "Red Lion of Castamere". By the end of the rebellion, Castamere had been put to the torch and all members of House Reyne executed. The title is thus a play on words, as the "rains" fall over the empty halls of the "Reynes" who have been killed to the last man, and "not a soul to hear".*

*The lyrics heavily reference the fact that the sigil of House Reyne was also a lion, but a red one instead of the golden lion used as the sigil of House Lannister. The rebellion of the Reynes against the Lannisters was thus seen as a civil war of lions.*

> "And who are you," the proud lord said,
>   "that I must bow so low?
>   Only a cat of a different coat,
>   that’s all the truth I know.
>   In a coat of gold or a coat of red,
>   a lion still has claws,
>   And mine are long and sharp, my lord,
>   as long and sharp as yours."
>   And so he spoke, and so he spoke,
>   that lord of Castamere,
>   But now the rains weep o’er his hall,
>   with no one there to hear.
>   Yes now the rains weep o’er his hall,
>   and not a soul to hear.
>   <sub>(318 characters)</sub>

For the TV show Game of Thrones, a tune was composed for the lyrics, and the indie rock band The National made the first rendition of it. You can listen to it [here](https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=ECewrAld3zw).

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

My own, non-golfed translation:

> "¿Y quién eres tú", dijo el orgulloso señor,
>  "para que yo deba hacer tanta reverencia?"
>  Solo un gato de diferente pelaje<sup><sub>[note 1]</sub></sup>,
>  esa es toda la verdad que sé.
>  Con pelaje rojo o pelaje dorado,
>  un león sigue teniendo garras,
>  y las mías son largas y afiladas, mi señor,
>  tan largas y afiladas como las vuestras".
>  Y así habló, y así habló,
>  el señor de Castamere,
>  pero ahora las lluvias lloran sobre su estancia,
>  sin nadie ahí que escuche.
>  Sí, ahora las lluvias lloran sobre su estancia,
>  y ni una alma se escucha<sup><sub>[note 2]</sub></sup>.
>  
>  <sub>(389 characters)</sub>

**Note 1**: 'coat' in English can mean "animal fur" as well as "coat of arms". It's a double entendre referring to houses Rayne and Lannister having similar coats of arms, both featuring a rampant lion but with different coat color.

**Note 2**: I think in 'not a soul to hear', the verb 'to hear' can be interpreted either as transitive: not a soul was left to hear the rains weeping, just like when it says before 'no one's there to hear'; or intransitive: everybody was dead, the place was silent, there was not a soul to hear -- as in there was nothing to hear, nobody alive to be heard.

**Concepts that *must* appear in the translation**:

- The name 'Castamere' or a reasonably argued translation or transliteration.
- The similarity in the coats and, specifically, the animal and colors. Lion, red, gold (or suitable synonyms) must be included.
- The Rayne lord saw his House as equally powerful as House Lannister.
- Literally everybody was killed.
- The Rayne lord spoke: you can golf his words as much as your ability allows, but they must still be shown as his words. I.e. if the song said *"Jolly," said the lord, "what a bright sun we have today!"* you could golf it to *"Sunny day!" he said*, but not to *It was sunny*.

As long as those concepts are kept and the gist of the story is still understood, you can make the text as short as you want.

---

General rules for this game are as follows:

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- **Rhyme bonus**: if you are up for a challenge, keep the number and rhyme of lines to get a **10% discount bonus** in your total char count!

  - The rhyming lines are those ending in *low/know*, *claws/yours* and *Castamere/hear*. To get the full bonus you must manage to get a *consonante* rhyme for those lines in Spanish; however, an *asonante* rhyme will still get you a good 5%. [Info about rhyme types in Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rima).
  - Please note that you don't need to keep the metric too: if you weren't allowed to make the lines shorter, there wouldn't be much golfing left to do ;-)

Also, remember that not every character counts for the total: only letters and numbers do. You can paste your translation in the letter counter linked below to obtain your char count.

- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contestants? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 231 caracteres (207,9 puntos con el bonus de rima)

> —¿Quién sois —dijo ufano el [lord](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NcHQvjE)—
>   para exigir tal [zalema](https://dle.rae.es/?id=cIWrE9Y)?
>   Un gato con otro pelo,
>   [hí](https://dle.rae.es/?id=KIFx9eO) está el tema.
>   Con pelo rojo o [guado](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JcudZRw),
>   uñas luce el león,
>   igual que las de vos,
>   largas, [buidas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6G48JW4) las mías son.
>
> Así [oró](https://dle.rae.es/?id=R8h4PV7) y oró,
>   el lord de Castamir,
>   ya llueve en su [*hall*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JzHz9Cq),
>   sin nadie para oír.
>   Sí, llueve en su *hall*,
>   ningún alma para oír.

Entiendo que si *Castamere* rima con *hear*, pronunciado /hi(ə)r/, una castellanización apropiada puede ser Castamir, que además rima con *oír* y hace el verso más fácil.

Se usa *orar* con su segunda acepción: *Hablar en público para persuadir y convencer a los oyentes o mover su ánimo.*

## 157 caracteres (versión en prosa)

> —¿Tal zalema mereces? —dijo ufano el lord—. Esto es así: con pelo rojo u oro eres felino como yo, ambos con garras mortales—. Así oró el lord de Castamir, mas ni un alma queda para oír la lluvia sobre su hall.

Comment: @walen creo que la norma no oficial era redondear hacia arriba, pero es tu pregunta y por tanto en caso de duda tú decides. :-)

Comment: @walen ¿Qué quieres decir con que "las palabras deben seguir siendo palabras"?

Comment: @walen es un cambio de _vos_ a _usted_, me has pillado. Es que era más corto que "vuestras".

Comment: @walen mira, lo he arreglado sin perder puntos. :-D

Answer (score 7):

## 252 caracteres

> ¿Qui sois, dijo el gran señor,
>   que exige tal fervor?
>   Un gato sol de piel dispar,
>   es lo que veo al cor;
>   de piel oro o carmesí,
>   un león es un león,
>   y yo soy tan feroz, milord,
>   tan feroz como vos.<sub>(half rhyme)</sub>
>
> Así habló, eso dijo,
>   el Lord de Castamere,
>   y en su castel diluvia ya,
>   y nadi la puede oír.
>   Sí, en su castel diluvia ya,
>   y ni un alma de oír.

---

Some poetic licence with some shortened/archaic words, given the pseudo-medieval setting of the books:

- [qui](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Uont3fH) = quien
- [sol](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YFFnS1v|YFFxu1L|YFGdevU|YFHUB5R) = solo
- [cor](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AndYLCe) = corazón
- [nadi](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QCTBvh1) = nadie
- [castel](https://dle.rae.es/?id=7qbGNql) = castillo

Have tried to keep the syllables roughly the same as the original so it matches the metre of the sung version.

Comment: Me declaro muy fan de esta traducción, aunque según el diccionario "par" equivale a "por", no a "para".

Comment: @walen no lo dudes. :-)

Comment: ¿Cómo se pronuncia *Castamere* para que rime con *oir*?

Comment: @blonfu In English I pronounce it /ˈkastamɪɹ/ so the rough Spanish pronunciation to me was /kastaˈmir/

Comment: (correction: in the English one the second /a/ should be a schwa)

Comment: Como ganador de esta edición, me gustaría ceder el turno de pregunta a ukemi por haber tenido su respuesta el doble de votos que las demás, y para que se anime a hacer su primera pregunta para el translation-golf, con mucha curiosidad por saber qué texto te animas a plantear. Si aceptas tienes dos días para escribir el siguiente reto. :-)

Answer (score 4):

### 228 (216,6 con bonus 5% rima asonante)

> "¿Quien eres" — dijo el gran señor
>   — que mi favor merezca?
>   Solo un gato de otro color,
>   esa es mi certeza.
>   Vista de rojo u oro,
>   tiene el león uñas,
>   las mías largas y agudas,
>   tanto como las tuyas."
>   Y así habló,
>   el señor de Castamir,
>   llueve en su casa,
>   nadie lo va a oír,
>   sí, llueve en su casa,
>   ni un alma lo va a oír.